# Logout from one Yii application logs out from all of them

Tags: yii

I have two yii projects, where second is a fork of first one. I noticed, that if I open both of them in the same time in two browser tabs, login in both apps and then log out in one of them, I'm immediately logged out of second one as well.

Is this a normal situation (Yii design feature -- i.e. it uses non-unique cookie for storing login state) or does this seems, that I made some mistake, when doing fork, and such thing should not happen at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set different [`sessionName`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#sessionName)s in your `config.php`. If not they use the same sessions.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Perfect answer! I'll just add for other's reference, that one have to set `'session'=>array('sessionName'=>'someuniquename'),` as an element of `components` array, in Yii application's configuration.